# Convert "Cartesian coordinates" to "polar coordinates with respect to user specified origin"

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I am trying convert few points in my image to polar coordinates in OpenCV. I came across function called cartToPolar which will give me polar coordinates for my points with respect to 0,0 being my origin. However I want to do this conversion by considering another point in my image as origin. Can anyone help me doing so? I came across posts which say that remap helps to shift the origin but I am not clear how it works.

Answer (score 2):

Then you have to move the ref point to origin:

```
px -= ref.x;  
py -= ref.y;
```

now pass (px,py) to the `cartToPolar` function